# Reference request: relationship between descriptions and things being described

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language

I am not at all educated in philosophy, but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I am looking for something that explores the relationship between the description of a thing, such as "red thing with a waxy texture and a sweet taste" and the thing being described (apple). Anything that analyzes the accuracy of descriptions or any relationship would be appreciated.

Comment: Useful : [Reference](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reference/) as well as [Descriptions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descriptions/).

Comment: The topic of scientific representation is dedicated to this kind of questions in the context of science (however it's not about descriptions in the linguistic sense, but generally about mathematical or physical models) see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-representation/

Comment: @Quentin Ruyant Thank you. That is precisely the kind of thing I'm looking for.